# Dynatrace added extra 90MB

Tags: amazon-web-services, npm, aws-lambda, dynatrace

New to Dynatrace and trying to Add dynatrace configuration to AWS lambda by changing package.json. Followed the document
https://www.npmjs.com/package/@dynatrace/oneagent

```
 "@dynatrace/oneagent": "^1.161.272-1.0.0"
```

But after npm install, understood that its taking 90MB+ of size.
is there any thing i missed to reduce the file lambda size?

Regards,
Santhoshkumar N.

Answer (score 2):

You can optimize the npm module for Lambda by following the instructions here: https://www.dynatrace.com/support/help/technology-support/cloud-platforms/amazon-web-services/installation/integrate-nodejs-lambda-functions/#optimizing-the-npm-module-for-lambda

> The Dynatrace npm module contains instrumentation code for a variety
>   of Node.js versions. As a Lambda function is always configured to run
>   a specific version of Node.js, it makes sense to only bundle those
>   parts of OneAgent that are applicable to this version.

To do this, go to the base directory of your application and execute:

```
# To prepare the package for Node.js 8 run
npx dt-oneagent-tailor --AwsLambdaV8

# To prepare the package for Node.js 10 run
npx dt-oneagent-tailor --AwsLambdaV10

# To prepare the package for Node.js 12 run
npx dt-oneagent-tailor --AwsLambdaV12

# To get a list of all options run
npx dt-oneagent-tailor
```

(`npx` is bundled with recent versions of `npm` - if it is not yet installed, install it with `npm install -g npx`)

Hope this helps.